# how to get values of "Post method parameters" in log of WAMP server

Tags: php, logging, wamp, wampserver

Example : 
I have a login form(login.php) which uses post method.When user access this page ,in log(access.log) it is reflected as:

"127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jun/2013:19:49:12 +0530] "**POST /users/login.php** HTTP/1.1" 200 2842"

I want to know the values passed (i.e username and password field values).How can I fetch these values to my log file.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP POST values are accessible from the `$_POST` [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), for example:

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
```

This assumes that the form is posted with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (default encoding for a html form with method `POST`) or `multipart/form-data` as the encoding type.

Other encoding types will require that you manually parse the post data which you can get from the file handle `php://input` like:

```
$postBody = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Thanks for makin it pretty :)

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I want to know these values in log file.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary and orangepill :  I am developing the third party generic application . I don't have permission to change code. I have access to modify config file . Is there any way to modify the config file and get post parameter values to log file ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of ... plus I don't know if that is a good idea from a security standpoint or from a log format standpoint (this would put the contents of every image uploaded into the log file)

Comment: Let me know when you find anything. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

use `$_POST[]` global array.
Name your inputs as `"uname", "passwd"`, then you can get the values from
`$_POST["uname"], $_POST["passwd"]`
and then in your php form action try to write them to the your log file.